# Database of injuries of inmates while awaiting trial in jail

Tags: data-request, legal

I am looking for a dataset listing injuries of inmates who were awaiting their trial in a jail. Injuries could be caused by anything, e.g. other inmates or neglects.

Here are some fields I would be interested to have:

- date/time
- jail location
- inmate demographics
- type of charges against the inmate
- type of injuries
- length of the state in the jail
- outcome of the trial

I am mostly interested in jails in the United States.